# how to access SSH through NAT in a VPC

Tags: networking, ssh, vpn, nat

I'm trying to figure out pros and cons of different approaches when accessing a `SSH` server inside a `VPN` through a `NAT` server

**Prerequisite:**

1- `key.pem` : .pem File for both servers (let's assume both servers use same .pem) :

2- public access server to SSH port `22` for `NAT` server : `55.55.55.55`

3- private access from NAT server  to SSH port `22` on server behind `NAT` server : `10.0.0.100`

As far as I know there are three approaches:

**1- Using Port forwarding -L option :**

from terminal one :

```
ssh -i key.pem -L 5555:10.0.0.100:22 user@55.55.55.55
```

from terminal two :

```
ssh -i key.pem -p 5555 user@localhost
```

**2- Using Agent forwarding**

```
  ssh-add -K key.pem

  ssh –A user@55.55.55.55
```

Then from another terminal :

```
  ssh user@10.0.0.100
```

**3- using proxy command by configuring /etc/ssh/ssh_config** (at least in ubuntu not sure about other OS)

adding the following to `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`

```
Host 10.0.0.100
    IdentityFile <ABSOLUTE FOLDER PATH>/key.pem
    ProxyCommand ssh -q -W %h:%p -i <ABSOLUTE FOLDER PATH>/key.pem user@55.55.55.55
```

then from terminal use:

```
  ssh user@10.0.0.100
```

I found option 3 the most convenient but not sure about its security.

So my question is in what circumstances should each approach be used? what are pros and cons?

Answer (score 1):

This method is called SSH-ing through a bastion host or a jumphost. Here's a short [article](https://estl.tech/ssh-into-the-dmz-via-a-bastion-host-85f90c94a8a9) that I wrote on this technique.

(1) and (3) are secure, but (3) is the most convenient one. It's the kosher way to do it, so-to-speak. The main difference in (3) is that `-W` makes SSH listen on stdin and forwards the packets to the final SSH endpoint, thru the jumphost. `-L` listens on a TCP socket that is opened on your client.

(2) is insecure so please don't use it. Read this [great writeup](https://heipei.github.io/2015/02/26/SSH-Agent-Forwarding-considered-harmful/) for more info. In short, `-A` opens a socket on the jumphost which forwards SSH auth requests back to the client. If the socket is compromised, the attacker can use the socket to authenticate to any host to which you have access.

`ssh`'s man page has a warning:

```
 -A      Enables forwarding of the authentication agent connection.  This can also be specified on a per-host basis in a configuration file.

         Agent forwarding should be enabled with caution.  Users with the ability to bypass file permissions on the remote host (for the agent's UNIX-domain
         socket) can access the local agent through the forwarded connection.  An attacker cannot obtain key material from the agent, however they can perform
         operations on the keys that enable them to authenticate using the identities loaded into the agent.
```